# Profile picture not showing column Person of Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have put JSON-code in the column "Person of Group" to show the profile picture of the person. It did work before, but now I am getting:

[image]

This is my JSON-code:

```
    {
 "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "flex-direction": "column",
  "align-items": "flex-start",
  "margin-top": "6px",
  "padding-right": "8px",
  "width": "100%",
  "overflow": "hidden"
    },
 "children": [{
  "forEach": "personIterator in @currentField",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
   "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
  },
  "style": {
   "display": "inline-flex",
   "align-items": "center",
            "height": "28px",
            "overflow": "hidden",
   "border-radius": "12px",
   "padding-right": "8px",
   "margin": "2px"
  },
  "children": [
            {
    "elmType": "img",
    "attributes": {
     "src": "='/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + [$personIterator.email]",
     "title": "[$personIterator.title]"
    },
    "style": {
     "width": "28px",
     "height": "28px",
     "display": "block",
     "border-radius": "50%"
    }
   },
   {
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "[$personIterator.title]",
                "attributes": {
                    "title": "[$personIterator.title]",
                    "class": "nameplate-title"
                },
                "style": {
                    "padding-left": "5px",
                    "white-space": "nowrap",
                    "font-size": "12px"
                }
            }
  ],
  "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]"
 }]
}
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: Are you able to access the picture directly with your SharePoint link 
 ? example https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/xyz/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?AccountName=test@test...com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and searching I have found my answer. You just have to add =@currentWeb:

```
 "src": "=@currentWeb + '/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=S&accountname=' + [$personIterator.email]",
 "title": "[$personIterator.title]"
```

Greetings, P.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the profile picture of person using SharePoint out of the box option in column settings without using JSON Formatting:

[image]

For more information, check: [How to show profile picture in Person column in SharePoint list/library?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-pnp-blog/how-to-show-profile-picture-in-person-column-in-sharepoint-list/ba-p/2265060)

---

**Update from comments**:

I just tried JSON code in your question & it is working fine for me.

**Proof**:

[image]

If it is not working for you, try using below JSON where I have replaced image `src` to `=[$personIterator.picture]`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "flex-direction": "column",
    "align-items": "flex-start",
    "margin-top": "6px",
    "padding-right": "8px",
    "width": "100%",
    "overflow": "hidden"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "personIterator in @currentField",
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLight ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "inline-flex",
        "align-items": "center",
        "height": "28px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-radius": "12px",
        "padding-right": "8px",
        "margin": "2px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "attributes": {
            "src": "=[$personIterator.picture]",
            "title": "[$personIterator.title]"
          },
          "style": {
            "width": "28px",
            "height": "28px",
            "display": "block",
            "border-radius": "50%"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "[$personIterator.title]",
          "attributes": {
            "title": "[$personIterator.title]",
            "class": "nameplate-title"
          },
          "style": {
            "padding-left": "5px",
            "white-space": "nowrap",
            "font-size": "12px"
          }
        }
      ],
      "defaultHoverField": "[$personIterator]"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: This is not the solution. The JSON-code is showing the profile picture bigger then when i put the slider "Show profile photos" to yes. But now it doesn't show anything anymore. And this option is not available for the columns Created By and Changed By.

Comment: Try using JSON given in my updated answer. Both JSON are working fine for me.